# including a PHP file from localhost gives warning

Tags: php

i have an index file with PHP code in localhost/KK/admin/pages

```
<?php
require_once 'url.php';
include 'localhost/KK/admin/pages/sidebar.php';
?>
```

url.php is within the same folder as index.php file. sidebar.php is in localhost/KK/admin/pages/admin/pages.

url.php has the code

```
<?php
$url = "localhost/KK";
?>
```

when i open index.php it gives me

> Warning: include(localhost/KK/admin/pages/sidebar.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\KK\admin\pages\index.php

and

> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'localhost/KK/admin/pages/sidebar.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\KK\admin\pages\index.php

can anyone explain why i am getting these errors and why i cant call sidebar.php? also a possible solution?

Comment: do you have the log with the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's traverse your directory: `localhost/KK/admin/pages/sidebar.php`

Your script file is located here: `C:\wamp64\www\KK\admin\pages\` or `KK\admin\pages\`

From `KK\admin\pages\` you ask for a **directory** (thats right, a directory **not** your server) `localhost`, from localhost to `KK` to `admin` to `pages`.

`include 'sidebar.php';` will do fine as the script is located in `KK\admin\pages\` and your include as well so you can include the file relative to the location of `index.php` located in `C:\wamp64\www\KK\admin\pages\`

Instead use the relative path, `..\` to go back 1 directory or use a constant to keep track of your root.

```
<?php
  const ROOT = 'C:\wamp64\www\';
  include ROOT . 'folder\file.php';
?>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be C:\wamp64\www\KK\admin\pages\sidebar.php

Comment: include 'localhost/KK/admin/pages/sidebar.php';

gives the same error.

Comment: no i know they are in the same folder. and if i write simply include 'sidebar.php'; it willwork. but i  want to be able to write $url/admin/pages/sidebar.php. where $url is required once  and  is "localhost/KK".

Comment: Then add a protocol, aka `http://localhost` otherwise it will treat it as a folder, but including a php script is not as easy as it sounds as it will execute the code on your server and include the output of the script.

Comment: wrapper is disabled error. if i enable it will it have security risks?

Comment: Obviously, it will if you allow user input straight into your `include()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114661/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-mohamed-athif).